# Some of my hard drive's files dissapeared- damaged

Tags: hard-drive

I connected my hard drive to my new Windows 10 PC (My old is Windows7) and some zip files go damaged and i couldn't open some photos.I got a message saying "file location could not be found".After i refreshed the folder, the files dissapeared.
Some photos didn't dissapeared but i couldn't open them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: Did you try : **right click** the **hard drive** in **Computer**, click **Properties**, then the tab **Tools**, and then click the **Check Now** button.